# Somebody's 'kind of'

Tags: phrase-usage, pronouns

I know the idiomatic usage of "somebody's kind of place/person/thing" to mean the types of place, person or thing that someone usually likes. But what about using it in the context below?

> I don't have **his kind of** mental strength.

Is this considered proper usage of the phrase?

For the purpose of clarification, I intended for the above sentence to have the same meaning as:

> I don't have the kind of mental strength he does.

Is it awkward to have a possessive pronoun before 'kind of XXX' instead of a normal pronoun after it to denote that XXX is of the type belonging/relating to the pronoun?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you've used it properly.

> I don't have **his** kind of mental strength.
>
> I don't have the kind of mental strength **he** does.

These two sentences have the same meaning.  They would usually be understood as meaning that the person *he* refers to  is mentally strong, and the speaker are not as mentally strong as he is.

This is is not strictly [entailed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entailment_(pragmatics)), so you could subvert the listener's expectation:

> I don't have the kind of mental strength he does.  I'm *even stronger* mentally!

But usually, you wouldn't do that, so the listener would understand it to mean the person *he* refers to is mentally stronger than the speaker.